# Is there a way to create a Traits class to parametrise Envelope_diagram_2 where the X monotone curves can be segments, rays or conic curves?

Tags: cgal, envelope

I am using the [`Envelope_3`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.9.1/Envelope_3/index.html) package of CGAL-4.9.1 and I need to compute an upper envelope where the resulting envelope diagram (`Envelope_diagram_2<EnvTraits>`) could have edges of three different types:

- segments
- rays
- parabolic arcs (conic arcs)

The three provided models of `Envelope_Traits_3` are not enough for this.
I therefore need to create my own `EnvTraits` (which have to be a model of the concept `Envelope_Traits_3`).

For now, I made a something like the already provided `Env_sphere_traits_3<ConicTraits>` model, with which I have at my disposal both parabolic arcs and segments (I just use straight arcs).

The problem arises because I also need to be able to use `Rays`. How could I do this? Is there a Traits class that I can extend (just like I'm doing right now with `Arr_conic_traits_2`) that provides `X_monotone_curve_2`s that can be of the three types that I need?

---

I found the `Arr_polycurve_traits_2` class, hoping that it would allow curves of different type to be stored as subcurves, but it actually just allows to store polycurves that are all of the same kind (linear, bezier, conic, circular...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a model of the `EnvelopeTraits_3` concept and of the `ArrangementOpenBoundaryTraits_2` concept. Among all traits classes provided by the "2D Arrangements" package only instances of the templates `Arr_linear_traits_2`, `Arr_rational_function_traits_2`, and `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2` are models of the later concept.

I suggest that you develop something like `Env_your_object_traits_3<AlgebraicTraits_2>`, where the template parameter `AlgebraicTraits_2` can be substituted with an instance of `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2`.

Efi

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits` is that the coefficients of the two variable polynomials can only be integers for now.

For now I figured that I can use `Arr_conic_traits` and represent rays as very long segments (the upper envelope is used to compute a farthest line segment voronoi diagram) that would then be cut when drawing the resulting diagram.

Comment: They can be also rationals, or at least, if you have rationals, you can convert them into integers. With conics, the situation is similar.

Comment: On the documentation there is specified that

_"the types_ `leda::integer` _and_ `CORE::BigInt` _are supported as well as any instance of_ `CGAL::Sqrt_extension` _that is instantiated with one of the integral types above."_

So I understood that I can only use integer numbers as coefficients. What do you mean with converting rationals to integers? Wouldn't that lose accuracy?

Comment: Your curve is the zero set of some polynomials with rational coefficient. You can multiply every coefficient with the denominators of all coefficients and retain the same curve. This way you obtain a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: I'm sorry for the previous comment, I didn't realise that. Thank you for your explanation and your patience!
However, in the end I have kept my current solution of using `Arr_conic_traits_2` and saving rays as _very_ (**_very_**) long segments.